# Bash function returns unexpected value

Tags: bash

```
function() {
   if something_that_will_fail; then
      irrelevantcode
   else
      echo "should be here"
      false
   fi
}

echo $function
```

This outputs "should be here". How do I get the `false` value?

Comment: `false` is a command that always has an exit status of 1, not a value.

Comment: Also, note that the function's exit status will be that of the last command in it. In this case, it's `false`, so the function will exit with a status of 1 (indicating failure), but if the function does *anything* after the `false` command, that status will change. That's why it's better to use something like `return 1` to control the function's exit status; `return`, by definition, *is* the last thing the function will execute, so it has complete control over the exit status.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing the *output* with *returned value*.

`$function` is a variable, you don't seem to populate it anywhere. To populate it with the output of the function, use

```
output=$(function_call)
```

The return value of a function can be retrieved from the special variable `$?`.

```
function_call
value=$?
```

If you want to use it in a condition, you often don't need the variable at all, as you can run the function directly in the condition:

```
function_call
if (( $? )) ; then
    echo There was an error
else
    echo Everything OK
fi
```

can be shortened to

```
if function_call ; then
    echo Everything OK
else
    echo There was an error
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash has no built-in boolean variables. Further, calling a function a la `$function_name` also seems wrong to me.

I am not sure, what you are trying to achieve, but you have two options there:

- You can output strings within your function and retrieve them afterwards.
- Additionally, you can also set the exit status of your function via the `return` key (this is what `return` is all about); here you can also specify a status code within a range 0-255 for your `return`, where **0** indicates that function terminated successfully, and all other numbers indicate the opposite.

Example:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function is_greater() {
   local value1=$1     
   local value2=$2

   if [[ $value1 -gt $value2 ]]; then
        printf "%s is greater than %s! \n" $value1 $value2
        return 0
   else 
        printf "%s is NOT greater than %s! \n" $value1 $value2
        return 1
   fi
}

what_func_says=$(is_greater 21 42)
func_exit_status=$?

if [[ $func_exit_status -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo $what_func_says
  printf "success code: %s \n" $func_exit_status
else
  echo $what_func_says
  printf "error code: %s \n" $func_exit_status
fi
```

Output:

```sh
21 is NOT greater than 42!
error code: 1
```